# How to iterate through a large APIM Policy programmatically using Java?

Tags: java, xml, azure-api-management

Consider this huge policy. If I need to add new node to marked node (A) as a child, what
would be the ideal way to traverse through the policy and reach the node to add node element as a child. Currently I am using `document.getElementByTagName` in a nested manner to reach the point and then adding node created by `document.createElement`. What would be the ideal approach ? Is there any better way to deal with policy in APIM as I will keep policies adding programmatically for most part using `Java`.

PS: This is just a sample APIM policy I use. You needn't go through the entire file. Just locate the (A) Part.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>*</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
            <expose-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </expose-headers>
        </cors>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@{                     var publicEndpoints = "{{ProductA-public-apis}}";                     var requestPath = context.Request.Method + "-" + context.Request.Url.Path;                     string[] publicEndpointsArr = publicEndpoints.Split(',');                     return publicEndpointsArr.Contains(requestPath);                 }">
                <set-header name="x-restricted-path" exists-action="append">
                    <value>false</value>
                </set-header>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized Realm" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
                    <openid-config url="https://oauth.theiris.club.com/auth/realms/vpm/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
                    <openid-config url="https://oauth.theiris.club.com/auth/realms/bnym-emg/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
                    <openid-config url="https://oauth.theiris.club.com/auth/realms/abcdefgh-india/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
                </validate-jwt>
                <set-variable name="token" value="@{
                    return context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","scheme param")
                                    .Split(' ').Last();
                }" />
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@{                         Jwt jwt;                         context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("token","")                                     .TryParseJwt(out jwt);                         string iss = jwt.Issuer  ;                                 return !(iss.Contains("https://oauth.theiris.club.com/auth/realms/"));                     }">
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized (Invalid Issuer)" />
                        </return-response>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise />
                </choose>
                <set-header name="x-user-id" exists-action="append">
                    <value>@{
                            Jwt jwt;
                            var roles = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("roles", "");
                            context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("token","")
                                        .TryParseJwt(out jwt);
                            
                            return jwt.Claims["sub"][0]; 
                        }</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-variable name="roles" value="@{
                        string allRoles = "UNKNOWN";
                        Jwt jwt;
                        context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("token","")
                                    .TryParseJwt(out jwt);
                        string realmRoles = (jwt.Claims["realm_access"][0]);
                        var realmRolesJson = JObject.Parse(realmRoles)["roles"];
                        allRoles = String.Join(",", realmRolesJson);
                        return allRoles;
                        }" />
                <choose> --------------------------------> (A)
                    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-org-id", "").Equals("66845034-db2a-4cde-8be9-015eedf316ae"))">
                        <rate-limit-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="ProductA-rate-limit-66845034-db2a-4cde-8be9-015eedf316ae" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-day-66845034-db2a-4cde-8be9-015eedf316ae" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="2147483647" renewal-period="15638400" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-sub-66845034-db2a-4cde-8be9-015eedf316ae" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                    </when>
                    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-org-id", "").Equals("ad591921-4b1b-457a-9af2-3c9437823a32"))">
                        <rate-limit-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="ProductA-rate-limit-ad591921-4b1b-457a-9af2-3c9437823a32" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-day-ad591921-4b1b-457a-9af2-3c9437823a32" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="2147483647" renewal-period="31536000" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-sub-ad591921-4b1b-457a-9af2-3c9437823a32" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                    </when>
                    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-org-id", "").Equals("7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a"))">
                        <rate-limit-by-key calls="1" renewal-period="60" counter-key="ProductA-rate-limit-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-day-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="2147483647" renewal-period="7776000" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-sub-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                    </when>
                    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-org-id", "").Equals("7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a"))">
                        <rate-limit-by-key calls="10" renewal-period="60" counter-key="ProductA-rate-limit-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-day-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="2147483647" renewal-period="2505600" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-sub-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                    </when>
                    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-org-id", "").Equals("7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a"))">
                        <rate-limit-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="ProductA-rate-limit-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-day-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="2147483647" renewal-period="2505600" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-sub-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                    </when>
                    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-org-id", "").Equals("7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a"))">
                        <rate-limit-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="ProductA-rate-limit-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-day-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="2147483647" renewal-period="2505600" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-sub-7debc949-579e-4173-9cdf-398f027df36a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                    </when>
                    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-org-id", "").Equals("de4c0b8d-0ede-4236-bf0d-bd6db6c3c92a"))">
                        <rate-limit-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="ProductA-rate-limit-de4c0b8d-0ede-4236-bf0d-bd6db6c3c92a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="1000" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-day-de4c0b8d-0ede-4236-bf0d-bd6db6c3c92a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                        <quota-by-key calls="2147483647" renewal-period="2678400" counter-key="ProductA-quota-per-sub-de4c0b8d-0ede-4236-bf0d-bd6db6c3c92a" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)" />
                    </when>
                    <otherwise />
                </choose>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://producta.club" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.LastError.Reason == "RateLimitExceeded")">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="429" />
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/json</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>{
                        "Limit Exceeded"
                 }</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

A Sample Part of Code, how I am doing this,
This is just to get to gist of what I am doing, to validate this approach.

```
private String getXMLWithUpdatedJWTPolicy(Document doc, String serviceName, Organization org) {
    Node validateJWTNode = getValidateJWTNode(doc, serviceName);
    Element openIdConfig = doc.createElement(NODE_OPENID_CONFIG);
    String openIdConfigUrl = String.format(openIdConfigBaseUrl, org.getRealm());
    openIdConfig.setAttribute(NODE_OPENID_CONFIG_ATTR_URL, openIdConfigUrl);
    validateJWTNode.appendChild(openIdConfig);
    // Create RateLimitSection if it doesnt exist.
    if(Objects.isNull(getQuotaAndLimitNodes(doc)) ){
        log.info("Found that there is not section for rate limiting");
        Node quotaLimitParent =  getQuotaAndLimitParentNodes(doc);
        Element rateLimitSection = doc.createElement("choose");
        rateLimitSection.setAttribute("id", GatewayConstants.RATE_LIMIT_SECTION_ID);
        Element otherwiseNode = doc.createElement("otherwise");
        rateLimitSection.appendChild(otherwiseNode);
        quotaLimitParent.appendChild(rateLimitSection);
    }
    setQuotaAndLimit(doc, org.getId());
    return policyService.convertDocumentToString(doc);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Java or JavaScript?

Comment: From the policy I understood that you are creating different rate limit policies for different clients. And this policy you are building on java. Say if a new client is being subscribed you will have a new policy for them. If its the right understanding can you paste the java code which you have currently and explain further

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Sorry for the Confusion. I am using Java.

Comment: @JustinMathew I have updated my code, to include the main function. Hope that suffices.

Comment: @Mahesh this is fine I dont see a problem with this approach. Anyway one or the otherway you need to locate the children and append it.